# Your Cloud Firestore database will start denying client requests unless you update your security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Your Cloud Firestore database will start denying client requests unless you update your security rules؟

what is mean this?

this is my rules in firebase

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 9, 3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See the question I linked, and *many* more from https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Your+Cloud+Firestore+database+will+start+denying+client+requests+unless+you+update+your+security+rules

Answer (score 3):

```
allow read, write: if
    request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 9, 3);
```

This code means that you're allowing all read and write requests to the database until September 3rd 2021.

If you instead want to allow reads and writes no matter the date, use this:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

But, rules exist for a reason, so you may want to read up on them on [the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)